# Convergence of $\sum \frac{(n-1)!e^{n-1}}{n^{n-1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The series given is:
$$1 + \frac{1! x}{2} + \frac{2! x^2}{3^2} + \frac{3! x^3}{4^3} + ...$$

The general term of the series is given by: $u_n = \frac{(n-1)!x^{n-1}}{n^{n-1}}$

To check the series' convergence, I used the D'Alembert's Ratio Test and evaluated $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}} = \frac{e}{x}$$
So, series is divergent if $x > e$ and convergent if $x < e$.

But, I am unable to get an answer when $x = e$. I tried evaluating the limit of $u_n$ to check if it turns out to be zero, but couldn't find it.

Can you help me identify the convergence in case $x = e$?

Comment: Do you know Stirling formula ?

Comment: No, I have no idea of Stirling formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u_n =\frac{e^{n-1} n !}{n^{n}}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$. This is the same sequence as you except I did not simplified the n in the fraction.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}} &=\frac{e^{n}(n+1) !}{(n+1)^{n+1}} \times \frac{n^{n}}{e^{n-1} n !} \\
&=e\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n} \\
&=e \exp \left(-n \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) \\
 &=e \exp \left(-n\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^{2}}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)\right)\right) \\
&=e \exp \left(-1+\frac{1}{2 n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right) \\
&=1+\frac{1}{2 n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) .
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore if n is big enough, $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_{n}} \geq 1$ and $(u_n)$ is increasing. Since $(u_n)$ is positive, it means $(u_n)$ does not converges towards 0. Therefore the series $(\sum u_n)$ diverges.

More generally, if d'Alembert's rule fails, then you can try to use test such as :
Raabe–Duhamel's test , Bertrand's test or Kummer's test (in order of generality of application of the test).

Comment: The limit of the ratio is 1, then how do you conclude ?

Comment: That's why I am using Taylor approximation to the second order. I am not using the D'Alembert's rule here. We don't need Stirling approximation even if it would probably work too.

Comment: ^^But this is a simpler proof right? It's showing that the ratio is strictly bigger than $1$ using elementary estimates which require less work than Stirling. Btw one can be non-asymptotic here - bounding the remainder term for the Taylor series of $\log(1+x)$ over $0< x < 1,$ $\log(1+x) < x - x^2/8,$ giving $u_{n+1}/u_n > \exp(1/8n) > 1.$

Comment: @Lelouch, thank you sirmfor your answer. Just wanted to confirm that in the last step, did you use the expansion for $e^x$?